# How can count how many times in specific time window value of column occured?

Tags: pandas, for-loop

I have time series data frame like
date: Jan, Feb, Mar, Aprl, May, June, July;itemID:12,12,12,12,12,12,12 price: 100,100,120,120,140,140,140

I have to check for which item  in last 6 months price have increased for two times.
First I have shifted column price so I can calculate the difference between price in current month and price for previous, but can someone help how can I apply some function or for loop with counter?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is sorted by date, you can group by itemID, ad check whether there are 2 or more occurrences of a positive `diff` in the last 6 items:

```
df.groupby('itemID')['price'].apply(lambda g: g.diff().tail(6).gt(0).sum()>1)
```

output:

```
itemID
12    True
Name: price, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thank you! I also tried with df['SMA_price'] = df.groupby('itemID').rolling(6)['check'].sum().reset_index(drop=True) and before that I defined check as difference in price between current and previous month is >0